# How do I block the expandable textarea feature in Firefox5 and up?

Tags: html, css, firefox, textarea, firefox-5

In Firefox 5 `<textarea>`s are expandable (bottom right corner there is a hook).

How do I make a textarea solid/un-expandable?
Preferably through CSS.

Comment: I didn't downvote (actually, I'd upvoted before), but my suspicion is that some would say taking off the resizability is evil because it defeats the accessibility feature that it was meant to introduce.

Comment: @Jacob Not voting has a different meaning from down-voting. It hints (or should) that there is something wrong with the question itself (either not clear/not to the subject or just spam).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this in your CSS:

```
textarea { resize: none; }
```